# how to read data from csv to feed them to cnn?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have the following csv structure:

image_id, class_name, color, browneyes, feature2, feature3, feature4

for example:

429759,dog,black,1,0,0,husky
352456,cat,white,0,0,0,any

how can i read the csv file so for each row it reads the image file and feeds it to the model? (the image_id is the image filename)

Answer (score 0):

you haven't mentioned what language you code in your question, but since you've mentioned Python in question's tags I show you an example in python

in python there is a nice python built-in module named **csv** that you can use it for working with CSV files

see the code below

CSV sample

```
name,department,birthday month
John Smith,Accounting,November
Erica Meyers,IT,March
```

Code

```
import csv

with open('employee_birthday.txt') as csv_file:
 csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
  line_count = 0
  for row in csv_reader:
    if line_count == 0:
        print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
        line_count += 1
    else:
        print(f'\t{row[0]} works in the {row[1]} department, and was born in {row[2]}.')
        line_count += 1
print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
```

reference : https://realpython.com/python-csv/

official docs :  https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: that's not what im asking for... the point is how can i prepare this data to feed them to a convolution neural network. basically image_id will be the filename which will be processed by the network and the other columns will be the labels or features for that image